# How can I merge complex elements as parameters into a macrodef in ant?

Tags: ant

How can I pass in multiple complex elements that are defined in external locations to a macrodef and also merge multiple versions of those elements so all of them are included?

This SO question is one version of this I tried, but apparently just can't work: [Apache Ant 1.8 macro invocation nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169845/apache-ant-1-8-macro-invocation-nesting)

I also tried this with PreSetDef and got the same result.

Here I'm using the example of include elements being passed to a cc compile task.

If I define a macro to compile some code, for example:

```
<macrodef name="do-compile">
    <element name="moreincludes" optional="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <cc>
            <includepath location="libs"/>
            <moreincludes/>
        </cc>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And I can execute it with complex arguments like:

```
<do-compile>
    <moreincludes>
        <includepath location="other-libs"/>
        <include-complex>
            <just-an-example/>
        </include-complex>
    <moreincludes>
</do-compile>
```

And the net result should become something like:

```
<cc>
    <includepath location="libs"/>
    <includepath location="other-libs"/>
    <include-complex>
        <just-an-example/>
    </include-complex>
</cc>
```

My problem is that I want to be able to define these complex arguments as partial values in multiple places, and have them all merge together in the final call to the macro. Sometimes, under some build conditions, certain version will be added in, and sometimes they won't.

For example, I may want to have this in one place, or under some condition:

```
<some-predefined-includes>
    <includepath location="libs"/>
</some-predefined-includes>
```

And have this in another place, or under some other condition:

```
<even-more-predefined-includes>
    <includepath location="other-libs"/>
    <include-complex>
        <just-an-example/>
    </include-complex>
</even-more-predefined-includes>
```

And then call the macro like so:

```
<do-compile>
    <moreincludes>
        <some-predefined-includes/>
        <even-more-predefined-includes/>
    </moreincludes>
</do-compile>
```

I don't see a way to accomplish this, which is basically just code reuse so I don't have to define sets of instructions multiple times. Macrodefs don't seem to support nested macros, and properties are just strings, not complex elements, so I don't understand what I need to do to handle this case. How can I pass in complex elements to a macrodef and also merge multiple options so all of them are included?

Comment: Would you be able to show your actual build script (in a gist or pastebin, if it's large)? It's hard to provide a good suggestion when we only have abstract requirements to go off of. All I can say right now is that macrodefs are probably the wrong approach.

Comment: I am not able to post any actual build scripts, no. I think I have explained pretty clearly what I am trying to do, and it is an abstract question because I don't really care how it can work, as long as it meets the goal of code reuse instead of having to duplicate the same commands under different conditions.

Comment: Do you actually need to run this macro multiple times during each of your builds, or are you just leveraging macrodef's nested element functionality because you don't see any better way of dynamically building a complex fileset?

Comment: I don't know that it needs to be a macro, but basically I need to compile an executable with a set of options, then compile a unit test executable to test the first with similar, but not exact options. Then, of course, how those options are set for each is different depending on the target of the build (OS, etc).

Comment: I'll add that if these options were just string parameters, this seems easy, but they are not, they are complex XML elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by complex XML elements. You're saying that your input data, separate from Ant, is stored in XML? Or you're referring to the Ant code you included above as an example?